# How can you use a DBIx helper with Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I would like to use a DBIx resultset helper, namely [`DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::Random`,](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aHelper%3a%3aResultSet%3a%3aRandom) in my Catalyst application.

The package documentation shows how it is loaded from a `DBIx::Class::ResultSet` class, but as far as I can tell, I have none of those because I'm using [`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader) to create the schema.

I have tried putting this `__PACKAGE__->load_components('Helper::ResultSet::Random')` in my `Schema::Result`, but that didn't work: *Can't locate object method "rand" via package "DBIx::Class::ResultSet".*

How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apply `DBIC::Helper::ResultSet::Random` to your Result class (eg. you already have `Schema/Result/Tbl.pm` which was created by `DBIC::Schema::Loader`).

`DBIC::Helper::ResultSet::Random` should be applied to ResultSet (not Result) class.

So, you just have to create `Schema/ResultSet/Tbl.pm` like this:

```
package Schema::ResultSet::Tbl;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'DBIx::Class::ResultSet';

__PACKAGE__->load_components('Helper::ResultSet::Random');

1;
```